# Why are the attributes of the objects from my ArrayList returning null?

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm writing code for a library (of books) in Java. I have a Book class with three attributes: Title, Author, and Genre. Genre is stored as an `int` because there are not that many:

```
public class Book {
  public  String title;
  
  public  String author;

  public  int genre;
  
  public Book() {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.genre = genre;
  }
  public void setBookTitle(String newBookTitle) {
    this.title = newBookTitle;
  }
  public void setBookAuthor(String newBookAuthor) {
    this.author = newBookAuthor;
  }
  public void setBookGenre(int newBookGenre) {
    this.genre = newBookGenre;
  }

  public String getBookTitle() {
    return  title;
  }
  public String getBookAuthor() {
    return author;
  }
  public int getBookGenre() {
    return genre;
  }
  public String toString() {
    LibraryDatabase libraryDatabase = new LibraryDatabase();
    
    return ("Title: "+this.getBookTitle() +
            "Author: " +this.getBookAuthor()+"Genre: " + this.getBookGenre() //edit this part to refer the integer to a String
            );
  }

  
}
```

I have a library database class for storing an ArrayList of books:

```
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class LibraryDatabase extends Book {
    ArrayList<Book> bookDatabase;
      public LibraryDatabase() {
       
      }
      public void books() {
        Book book1 = new Book();
    
        book1.setBookTitle("Harry Potter");
        book1.setBookAuthor("J.K. Rowling");
        book1.setBookGenre(1);
      }
    
      public ArrayList<Book> getArrayList() {
        return bookDatabase;
      }
      
    }
```

Lastly, I have a Customer class that basically just organizes all of the above into a user-friendly interface:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Customer {
  
  public Customer() {
  }

  public void run() {
    System.out.print("Welcome to Generic Library Service. Please enter your name.");
    Scanner kbEater = new Scanner(System.in);
    String customerName = kbEater.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Would you like to borrow, return, or donate a book?");
    System.out.println("    1. Borrow");
    System.out.println("    2. Return");
    System.out.println("    3. Donate");
    Scanner kbNeeder = new Scanner(System.in);
    int customerChoice = kbEater.nextInt();
    switch (customerChoice) {
      case 1: borrow();
      break;
      //case 2: returnBook();
      //case 3: donate();
    }
  }
  public void printGenres() {
    
    System.out.println("    1. Fantasy");
    System.out.println("    2. Science Fiction");
    System.out.println("    3. Dystopian");
    System.out.println("    4. Action & Adventure");
    System.out.println("    5. Mystery");
    System.out.println("    6. Horror");
    System.out.println("    7. Thriller & Suspense");
    System.out.println("    8. Historical Fiction");
    System.out.println("    9. Romance");
    System.out.println("    10. Graphic Novel");
    System.out.println("    11. Young Adult");
    System.out.println("    12. Children's");
    System.out.println("    13. Memoir & Biography");
    System.out.println("    14. Food");
    System.out.println("    15. Art & Photography");
    System.out.println("    16. Self-improvement");
    System.out.println("    17. History");
    System.out.println("    18. Travel");
    System.out.println("    19. Humor");
    System.out.println("    20. How-to");
    System.out.println("    21. Science & Tech");
  }
  
  public void borrow() {
    System.out.println("What is the genre of the book you're looking for?");
    printGenres();
    Scanner kbMeter = new Scanner(System.in);
    int genre = kbMeter.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Do you want to see titles, or are you looking for a particular author?");
    System.out.println("    1. Titles now");
    System.out.println("    2. Search by author");
    Scanner kbLeader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int titleOrSearch = kbLeader.nextInt();
    switch(titleOrSearch) {
      case 1:
      titlesNow();
      break;
      case 2:
      //method for searching by author
    }

  }
  public void titlesNow() {
    LibraryDatabase libraryDatabase = new LibraryDatabase("1", "1", 2);
    System.out.println(toString());

  }
  
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Welcome to Generic Library Service. Please enter your name. **Username**
Here are our books:
Title: nullAuthor: nullGenre: 0
```

Why is this happening? Why are the attributes returning null? I want to list all the books' titles, authors, and genres from the Book ArrayList. Because there's currently only one book, it should print out that book(Harry Potter by J.K. Rowling).

Comment: In `books`, you create a `new Book`, set some of its values... then the function ends and you throw that book away.

Comment: The book first needs to be added to the arraylist before you can loop through it and access the fields.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here, in the constructor:

```
public Book() {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.genre = genre;
}
```

You are assigning `title, author, genre` to themselves, which are all `null`. To fix this, simply pass in some parameters to the constructor:

```
public Book(String title, String author, int genre) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.genre = genre;
}
```

and everything should work instead of having to use the setter methods.

The printing wrong is because of the fact that you don't save your `book1` anywhere. In your constructor for `LibraryDatabase`, add `bookDatabase = new ArrayList<>();` and at the end of the `books()` function, add a `bookDatabase.add(book1);`.

Also, note that your `LibraryDatabase` does not do anything in your `toString()` method.

Comment: That throws an error in the LibraryDatabase class asking for parameters when I call the Book object.

Comment: You have to add the parameters into the constructor as well, not just the `new Book(title, author, genre);`. That way you'll have a correct constructor matching the one you called.

Comment: There are many instances of Book and LibraryDatabase being called as objects across the program. Do I need to insert parameters into all of these? And what exactly do I insert, just phony strings and ints?

Comment: Well in your example, you would put in "Harry Potter",... Etc. What @null_awe is suggesting replaces using your setters, so when you construct your book you input the title etc. You could just get rid of the code in your constructor, but it would make **a lot more** sense to do it there.

Comment: Alright, I did all this. It's still not being printed in the way I want, returning:
```Customer@214c265e```

Comment: That implies that you are printing an object of the `Customer` class. Do you have such a class and could you provide the code?

Comment: I have a Tester class that instantiates Customer. But I don't think the code for that class is necessary, all it does is basically instantiate Customer. I edited the original post to include the Customer class.

Answer (score 0):

Change your LibraryDatabase as below

```
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class LibraryDatabase extends Book {
    ArrayList<Book> bookDatabase;
      public LibraryDatabase() {
       
      }
      public void books() {
        Book book1 = new Book();
    
        book1.setBookTitle("Harry Potter");
        book1.setBookAuthor("J.K. Rowling");
        book1.setBookGenre(1);
        bookDatabase.add(book1);
      }
    
      public ArrayList<Book> getArrayList() {
        return bookDatabase;
      }
      
    }
```

Add that `book1` to your arraylist. Also add @null_awe code. you are missing that too .

```
   public Book(String title,String author,int genre) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.genre = genre;
  }
```